# Proof for clustering in a network of friendship

Tags: algorithms, graphs, clustering

Consider an undirected graph $G = (V, E)$ representing the social network of friendship/trust between
students. We would like to form teams of three students that know each other. The question
is to decide whether the network allows for enough such teams, without checking all the triples
of graph $G$. For this reason, we use random sampling to design an efficient estimator of the
number of connected triples.
We partition the set of node triples into four sets $T_0, T_1, T_2$, and $T_3$. A node triple $v1, v2, v3$
belongs to

- $T_0$ iff no edge exists between the nodes $v1, v2$, and $v3$,
- $T_1$ iff exactly one of the edges
  $(v1, v2)$, $(v2, v3)$, and $(v3, v1)$ exists,
- $T_2$ iff exactly two of the edges $(v1, v2)$, $(v2, v3)$, and $(v3, v1)$
  exist,
- $T_3$ iff all of the edges $(v1, v2)$, $(v2, v3)$, and $(v3, v1)$ exist.

$|T_3|$ denotes the number of connected triples in the graph that is the quantity we need to
estimate.
Consider the following algorithm:

• Sample an edge $e = (a, b)$ uniformly chosen from $E$

• Choose a node $v$ uniformly from $V \ {a, b}$

• if $(a, v) ∈ E$ and $(b, v) ∈ E$ then $x = 1$, else $x = 0$

Show that $|T1| + 2|T2| + 3|T3| = |E|(|V | − 2)$

Any solution?

Comment: What did you try and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Sincerely I don't know how to start to prove this, I have no idea.

Comment: Can you tell us where you encountered this task?  You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove the euqality : 
Let e=(v,w) be an of the graph G=(V,E), to construct a triple with "e" you can choose any vertex from "a" in the set V{v,w} this will give you either a triple in the set T1 or T2 or T3. This is the algorithm explained in your text, For every "e" edge in E, 3 cases are possible :

1- (a,e)=(a,v,w) in T1 => we will count it one time.

2- (a,e)=(a,v,w) in T2 => we will count it twice, first time with the edge e and the vertex "a", second time when we will choose one of the possible edges (a,w) (or (a,v)) (only one exist because (a,e) is in T2) with the vertex v (or respec w).

3- (a,e) in T3 => we will count it 3 times like the previous case.

The number of triples generated by this algorithm is : |E|(|V|-2) because of every edge we test all possible |V|-2, the triples in T1 will be generated one time, in T2 two times, in T3 3 times due to the 3 possibles options showen before. Thus the equality : |T1|+2|T2|+3|T3|=|E|(|V|-2)

I hope it was usefull :D